# How to create kdbx file in python

Tags: python, keepass

I'd like to know if there is a way, in python to create a keypass file (.kdbx). With this, I want to fill it with passwords and export it. I tried to juste create a file and use the pykeepass module to fill it but I met errors :

```py
f = open("test.kdbx", "w")
kp = PyKeePass("test.kdbx", "test")
group = kp.add_group(kp.root_group, "test")
kp.add_entry(group, "coucou", "username", "password")
kp.save()
f.close()
```

but it threw me :
[image]

(the file is empty)

Do you know a way to fill this file correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the [example](https://github.com/libkeepass/pykeepass#example) in PyKeepass:

Instead of `kp = PyKeePass('db.kdbx', password='somePassw0rd')` to  load an existing database, use [`create_database()`](https://github.com/libkeepass/pykeepass/blob/master/pykeepass/pykeepass.py#L901) to create a new one:

```py
from pykeepass import PyKeePass, create_database

# create a new database at filename with supplied credentials.
# returns PyKeePass object.
kp = create_database ('newDb.kdbx', password='s3cr3t', keyfile=None, transformed_key=None)

# create a new group
group = kp.add_group(kp.root_group, 'email')

# create a new entry
entry = kp.add_entry(group, 'gmail', 'myusername', 'myPassw0rdXX')
print(entry)  # Entry: "email/gmail (myusername)"

# save database
kp.save()
```